# Access and show HTML Div Element from ASP.NET CORE MVC C#

Tags: c#, .net, twitter-bootstrap, asp.net-core, razor

I want to show my bootstrap alert from my C# Controller code.

Currently I am using HTML form and submitting it to my Home Controller. Controller saves data to SQL server and redirect me to the Homepage Index.cshtml.

After saving data I want to show bootstrap confirmation "Data Saved Successfully".

Here is my code

Controller:-Please also suggest If any improvement required in my controller code

```
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult SaveEmp(EmployeesModel _model)
        {
            string CS = this.Configuration.GetConnectionString("SQLConn");
            using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(CS))
            {
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SP_SaveEmp", conn);
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                conn.Open();

                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EmployeeID", _model.EmployeeId);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", _model.Name);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Gender", _model.Gender);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Age", _model.Age);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Position", _model.Position);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Office", _model.Office);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@HiringDate", _model.HiringDate);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Salary", _model.Salary);
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                conn.Close();
            }

            TempData["AlertMessage"] = _model.Name 
            return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
        }
```

My View

```
@*Bootstrap Alert*@

<div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissible fade show" style="display:none; padding: 5px" role="alert" runat="server" id="bootstrapAlert">
    <svg class="bi flex-shrink-0 me-1" width="24" height="24" role="img"><use xlink:href="#info-fill" /></svg>
   Records Updated Successfully !
    <button type="button" class="btn-close" aria-hidden="true" style="padding:10px" aria-label="close" onclick="closeAlert()"></button>
</div>


My Form


<div class="row form-group">
<div class="col-md-12 col-md-auto">
@using (Html.BeginForm("SaveEmp", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "EmpCreateForm" }))
                        {
                            @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
                            @Html.ValidationSummary()
                            @Html.TextBox("EmployeeID", "EmployeeID", new { @style = "Display:none;", id = "EmpIDModal" })
                            <span class="form-control-label">@Html.Label("Name")<span style="color:red">* </span></span>
                            @Html.TextBox("Name", null, new { @class = "form-control", id = "namebox" })

}

<button class="btn btn-success btn-rounded" type="submit" id="savebtn" form="EmpCreateForm"><span class="spinner-border-sm"></span>Save</button>

</div>
</div>
```

Please suggest how do I show my bootstrap alert on data saving ?

PS: ASP.NET CORE doesn't use System.Web.UI

Thanks

Comment: MVC is a server-side technology, so you can't run client-side directly. What you can do is write the Bootstrap into the Razor on postback, so the alert will be shown when the page is rendered.

Comment: do not use form submit but jquery ajax instead, then you can handle the callback event

Comment: @AvrohomYisroel How to use Razor for Bootatrap ??

Comment: @TinyWang   ASP.NET CORE has introduced new technique called Tag Helper, I am sure there is a way around to access HTML tags from C# .Net Core.

Comment: @SoftwareDeveloper Razor and Bootstrap are two different technologies. Razor allows you to generate HTML (and CSS, JavaScript, etc) from server-side code. Bootstrap gives you a load of helper CSS classes, HTML components, etc to help you build rich UIs. As I said before, you can write Bootstrap code (which is basically HTML) into your page from the Razor when you need it. It may be helpful to read up on the ASP.NET MVC page life cycle, as this should all become a lot clearer.

Comment: @SoftwareDeveloper As for helper tags (which aren't at all new by the way!), they are merely a way of helping you package up some HTML into a server-side component. Not sure what you mean by "_access HTML tags from C# .Net Core_", but I'm almost certain it doesn't mean what you think. Read up about the page life cycle and it should clarify things a lot.

Comment: @AvrohomYisroel Thanks, I will check that out.. I just want to access HTML div from C# without using Jquery-Ajax. Anyway let me check Razor docs.

Comment: @SoftwareDeveloper Part of the beauty of Razor (and even more so with Blazor) is that it greatly reduces the amount of JavaScript you need to write. Depending on how mature your project, I would look carefully at Blazor, as it's amazingly powerful, and makes web development sooooo much easier